# what's the right place to ask an identification question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

My question is about identifying a book of piano music from my childhood. It's the sort of question that (in its domain) [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) handles all the time. Here it'd clearly not be [on-topic](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Is there a site in the Stack that would be good for this? If not, do you have a list of forums that you tend to recommend to users?

Comment: Although it's off-topic on the main site, you could alwasy try asking in [our chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room).

Comment: Possibly https://www.reddit.com/r/Music/

Comment: Do you remember the title? If so you can search the net, libraries ,sheet music sites, if it is already public domain maybe you can look it up on the site of islmp. They have alot of titles and genres. You could search  by three methods. 1. composers 2. instrument  3. even tap in the tune. It's fabulous what you can find there.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like it may be on topic over on [Music Fans](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange.

Comment: The identification questions on the Music Fan SE are for genre, album, song/music video, and performer. It's not really for identifying sheet music or finding a book containing specific songs as it really doesn't match the audience there.